Distance between evenly distributed points on a sphere
Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ be number of points on the unit sphere, such that the minimal distance between any 2 points is as large as possible (I guess this is the mathematical formulation to describe an "equal distribution" of points on the sphere, such as the distribution that fibonnaci sphere aims to generate).
If such a distribution is given, is there a way to calculate the angle between 2 adjacent points? (the angle between the vector that connects the center of the ball with one point, and the vector that connects the center of the ball with the other point).
Equivalently, is there a way to find a general expression that depends on $N$ for $\phi$ and $\theta$ of adjacent points? (in that case we can use cosine distance to calcualte the angle).
Thanks.

Also this question and this question
